# Why `git show-ref FETCH_HEAD` is empty?

Tags: git, fetch

I fetched remote repository, and the reference to it stored in `FETCH_HEAD`, it has some content

```
cat .git/FETCH_HEAD     
# => d11f8ef4a4735a4193633ed2fed90e441d9ce0f8 branch 'hotfix' of xxx
```

But `git-fetch` shows nothing

```
git show-ref FETCH_HEAD 
# => nothing
```

Why? And how to get SHA of last commit from FETCH_HEAD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `rev-parse` instead of `show-ref`:

```
git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD
```